# Lista dentro do Layout do Spinner

Tags: java, android, android-layout, spinners

Olá, 
Gostaria de saber se tem como colocar a lista que está dentro do Spinner diretamente no layout.

Normalmente eu faço assim:

```
 horario = new ArrayList<>();
    horario.add("");
    horario.add("Aberto Hoje");
    horario.add("Não importa");
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplication(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, horario);
    spinnerhora.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Gostaria de colocar dentro do xml.
Obrigada

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declare no seu arquivo strings.xml

```
<string-array name="options">
<item>Aberto hoje</item>
<item>Não importa</item>
</string-array>
```

E o seu spinner:

```
<Spinner 
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
        android:entries="@array/options"
    />
```

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4029623/7141389)

Comment: Nossa, muito obrigada! Perfeito!

Comment: Oi Hugo, mas uma coisa, mudou a cor do texto do meu spinner com isto. Sabe como posso alterar a cor do texto?

Comment: Dê uma olhada nessa resposta `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159113/android-where-is-the-spinner-widgets-text-color-attribute-hiding`